# Why can't std::ref be used to pass objects into Boost.Python modules?

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python, boost-ref

Environment: Boost 1.61.0 compiled with Python 3.5

The following C++ code outputs `12`:

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    int func() { return 12; }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(bridge)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    class_<A>("A", no_init)
        .def("func", &A::func);
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    PyImport_AppendInittab("bridge", PyInit_bridge);
    Py_Initialize();
    using namespace boost::python;

    dict dictMain = extract<dict>(import("__main__").attr("__dict__"));

    import("bridge").attr("a") = boost::ref(a);
    exec("import bridge", dictMain);
    exec("print(bridge.a.func())", dictMain);
}
```

However, if I replace `boost::ref` with `std::ref`, a `boost::python::error_already_set` instance is thrown.

Why cannot `std::ref` be used here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice article about [handling python exceptions in C++](https://misspent.wordpress.com/2009/10/11/boost-python-and-handling-python-exceptions/). Any way I guess python through exception `AttributeError` because of difference in `reference_wrapper` implementations in [std](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost/reference_wrapper.html) and [boost](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) libraries. You can see difference even in public interface. `std::reference_wrapper` has no `get_pointer()` method.